# Reading all response cookies in Axis 1.6.2 client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

Apache Axis 1.6.2 reads only the last Cookie
In my response I have 3 cookies, however I am able to read only last one

I want to check in the code whether there is a cookie with name WDISessiion

```
MessageContext msgCtx = stub._getServiceClient().getLastOperationContext().getMessageContext(WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_IN_VALUE);

CommonsTransportHeaders cth = (CommonsTransportHeaders) msgCtx.getProperty(MessageContext.TRANSPORT_HEADERS);

String cookie = (String) cth.get(HTTPConstants.HEADER_SET_COOKIE);
```

I want to be able to read all the cookies. or atleast the specific cookie with name WDISession

Refer this image for how cookies are returned in Postman
[image]